# No hard rule break allowed even nullable solution is ok in VRS

Tags: java, optaplanner

I am using Vehicle routing module from OptaPlanner. In this example on website Vehicle must visit all the customers, no matter if it is breaking hard constraint (capacity etc).
Is it possible technically in the code to achieve that no hard rule get break even less or no assignment of vehicle and customer happens.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand the question correctly you're talking about over-constrained planning situation where the sum of demands of all customers is greater than the total capacity of the vehicle fleet.

You would like OptaPlanner to only propose feasible solutions, i.e. without exceeding capacity of any vehicle (because it's not physically possible) even at the cost of not visiting all customers (which is physically possible).

I believe this is currently not possible due to the way the vehicle routing domain is modeled. It is called [variable chaining](https://docs.optaplanner.org/latest/optaplanner-docs/html_single/#chainedPlanningVariable). In this case, every initialized entity (customer) is part of a chain. Unvisited customer would be a customer that is not part of any chain, thus an uninitialized entity, but solver cannot uninitialize entities.

As a workaround, you could use a ghost vehicle entity with unlimited capacity and use it as a fallback to visit customers that cannot be visited by real vehicles due to capacity limitations. With this approach you would have to adjust scoring function to incentivize using real vehicles over the ghost one.

Comment: Thanks for the answer.And you got my point precisely And the workaround also worked for me.